# jest how to test a function inside of a react component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have been trying to test a function inside of a react component to get 100% coverage but I am been searching for answers but was stuck so coming here for your help. Below is my code. How can I make a jest mock out of the deleteHandler inside Schedule.tsx. My coverage report is asking me to test this code.

Schedule.tsx

```
const Schedule : FunctionComponent<{id: number, name: string, time: string}> = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { deleteSchedule } = bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);

  const deleteHandler = () => {
    deleteSchedule(props.id);
  };

  return (
    <ScheduleContainer>
      <ButtonDelete onClick={deleteHandler}>x</ButtonDelete>
      {props.name} - Time: {props.time}
    </ScheduleContainer>
  );
};

export default Schedule;
```

I tried below method but realized that my test block cannot receive the deleteHandler from my mockComponent function because of block scoping

Schedule.test.js

```
const renderWithRedux = (
  component,
  { initialState, store = createStore(reducer, initialState) } = {}
) => {
  return {
    ...render(<Provider store={store}>{component}</Provider>),
  };
};

const mockComponent = () => {
  const deleteHandler = jest.fn();

  return <Schedule />;
}

test("handle click", () => {
  renderWithRedux(mockComponent);
  const deleteButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "x" });
  fireEvent.click(deleteButton);
  expect(deleteHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Comment: What exactly do you think is the connection between the `deleteHandler` you define in the tests and the `Schedule` component you're actually testing?

Comment: i am trying to mock the deleteHandler that is from Schedule component so that I can test that it is being called

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but the jest.fn you create in in your tests has _absolutely nothing_ to do with the implementation you're exercising. Not only that but if you _had_ successfully mocked it out how would that help _increase_ coverage?! Test the _behaviour_, in this case the interaction with the service it collaborated with.